# Elasticsearch - Does it matter to which node I send an update?

Tags: elasticsearch

In an elastic cluster with muliple nodes, one master, does it matter to which node a document update or delete request hits.

Currently I find out the master node by asking one of the nodes which returns a complete list of all nodes and the master node ID which I then use to get the transport address for. I then point all update traffic at that transport address.

Can requests be sent to any node (as long as they are available) with no issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, it doesn't matter.  Send data to any node you like.

An important thing to remember is that the "master" node will change over time.  Let's say you have 3 node cluster and node A is the master.  If node A ever goes down for maintenance then node B or C will become the master.

Another important node: you never need to know which node is the master.  That's just wasted query time.  Send the data to A, B, or C, they are all the same.  Don't try to outsmart ES, let the product do a lot of this work for you.

We have a 3 node production cluster behind a load balancer and round-robin the incoming requests to all 3 nodes.

Comment: We also have a 3 node cluster with a round-robin load balancer. Thanks for the information!